# recording quota api in twilio REST api

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

is there an api in twilio that can tell the remaining quota of the recordings out of the 10000 mins that are freely available. we have saved the recording on twilio and want to delete the older ones so that we will not exhaust the free quota.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Usage API with the respective category.

REST API: Usage Records
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record#usage-categories

> recordings     Recordings of voice calls. Count is the number of
>   recordings and Usage is the number of recorded minutes.